# How to Click on Checkbox based on class in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

see website code:
[image]

There are multiple td class='timeslotCellNonPeak", and each of these td class has the xpath:

```
//*[@id="searchResultTable"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3], 
//*[@id="searchResultTable"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4],
//*[@id="searchResultTable"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5], 
...
```

Within some of these td classes, I have a checkbox that I want to click. My ultimate goal is to define a td class to search in, say

```
//*[@id="searchResultTable"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]
```

then click the checkbox if it is present.

I have tried looking for boxes with

```
id=gwt-uid-102
```

but that won't work as the id is different everytime.

In short I want to:

```
i = # i will define a number here
tdClass = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="searchResultTable"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[i]")

# then within this tdClass, click the checkbox if checkbox is present.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this "Code not tested":

```
check_boxes =  driver.find_elements_by_class_name('timeslotCellNonPeak')
for box in check_boxes:
    try:
         box.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="checkbox"]')
    except Exception as e:
         print('Checkbox not found')
```

Comment: I don't need to loop through all of the boxes to check if checkboxes are available. I just want to search through specific ones that I define. How would I do that?

Comment: Just tried your answer, problem this code have is that say box 1 has a checkbox, it can successfully click the checkbox. However, box 2 does not have a checkbox, and I think the searching for checkbox searches all the boxes, and results in unchecking the checked checkbox from box 1.

Comment: Is there a text on the same row as the checkbox? you can look for a specific text, find which row it is and click a checkbox on the same row.

Comment: nope, no text on the checkbox

Comment: so the only differential between the checkboxes is the id?

Comment: yes, that is why I want to use the timeslotCellNonPeak to find the checkboxes

Comment: driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@type="checkbox"]') will find all checkbox elements, loop thru and click maybe

Comment: yes, but the problem is I don't want to click all checkboxes. I only want to click the checkboxes from the timeslotsNonPeak that I decide.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240023/discussion-between-victor-picinin-and-hbae).

Answer (score 0):

To identify whether `checkboxes` present in a table cell for a specific row you can use the following `xpath` to identify that and then iterate and click.

```
checkboxes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='searchResultTable']/table/tbody/tr[2]//td[.//input[@type='checkbox']]//input[@type='checkbox']")

for chk in checkboxes:
   chk.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have decided on these indexes they can be utterly random. You can use f string to create your xpath. Then try to click that element.

```
rows=[3,4,5]
for row in rows:
    xpath=f"//*[@id='searchResultTable']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[{row}]/span[1]/input[1]"
    print(xpath)
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
    except:
        continue
```